# Max Average For All Durations

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to find all possible maximum contiguous subarray averages from an array of values. Each array value represents the value at a duration, the number of seconds passed.

Ex. Input = [6, 4, 3, 10, 5]

Ex. Output = [5.6, 5.75, 6, 7.5, 10]

Output[0] = 6+4+3+10+5 / 5 = 5.6

Output[1] = 6+4+3+10 / 4 = 5.75

Output[2] = 3+10+5 / 3 = 6

Output[3] = 10+5 / 2 = 7.5

Output[4] = 10 / 1 = 10

The issue is that the real data has length of up to 40,000 values.

The result should have the same length as the input. I‘ve done a reduce on a subarray of specific lengths (only getting 5s, 60s, 3600s, etc. length), but that’s not a viable solution for each possible duration. Is there a way I can partition or otherwise create a specialized data structure to get these values? If not, how can I exclude durations as I go?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I’ve tried Kadane’s algorithm for max sum of a subarray of length k, repeated for each possible length. I implemented that with an array reduce. I haven’t conceptualized a way to do it faster than searching every possible subarray of length k, which is way too slow to function.

Comment: This is close, thanks a lot! I think I’ve missed explaining it properly, but there are cases where the maximum average for a given duration, let’s say 2s, won’t necessarily fall immediately after the 1s maximum average. 

Example: input = [10, 0, 1, 1, 1, 9, 2]
The maximum 2s average here is 9+2/2=5.5, at indices 5 and 6, but the 1s average is 10 at index 0. So the output would be [10, 5.5, ...] This won’t work for that case.

This is a reply to below reverse answer*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just take the reverse of the input array, then calculate sum and average incrementally. Then again taking the of output array.

```
const input = [6, 4, 3, 10, 5].reverse();

let output = [];
let total_sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    total_sum += input[i]; 
    let avg = total_sum / (i + 1);
    output.push(avg);
}
console.log(output.reverse());
```

(You can even eliminate the reverse by looping the for loop in reverse order.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not `.map()`? Mixed with reduce you could do something like this:

```
const output = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8]
];

const averages = output.map(
  subarray =>
    subarray.reduce(
      (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
      0
    ) / subarray.length
);
```

Where `subarray` is the collection of values, they're then added together and divided by the length of the subarray.

I hope this is what you mean

Comment: Thanks for the reply! See above comment for an issue with this reply. It’s close, but it’s not quite there.